# HttpAddFragmentToCache and OS error 50

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, http, http.sys

I am trying to create an embedded web server in an application. For this I use the http.sys HTTP server component from Windows. Everything works well when I do not try to use `HttpAddFragmentToCache`.

What I did so far (removed any error checking but without the fragment caching it works OK):

```
HttpInitialize( HTTPAPI_VERSION_1, HTTP_INITIALIZE_SERVER );
HttpCreateHttpHandle( FQueueHandle )
HttpAddUrl( FQueueHandle, PWideChar( W ) );
...
HttpRemoveUrl( FQueueHandle, PWideChar( W ) );
HttpTerminate( HTTP_INITIALIZE_SERVER );
```

Now when a request comes by in a helper thread:

```
HttpReceiveHttpRequest( FQueueHandle, FRequestID, 0, FRequest^, FRequestBufferSize, @Bytes );
// if needed:
HttpReceiveRequestEntityBody( FQueueHandle, FRequestId, 0, @FRequestContent[ 0 ], Longword( N ), @BytesRead )
// Fill in chunks...
// Respond
HttpSendHttpResponse( FQueueHandle, FRequestId, 0, FResponse, nil, N );
```

What I am trying to change is to add some static documents to the fragment cache (at the ellipsis above):

```
Chunk.DataChunkType           := hctFromMemory;
Chunk.FromMemory.pBuffer      := @Content[ 0 ];
Chunk.FromMemory.BufferLength := Length( Content );
Policy.Policy                 := hcpUserInvalidates;
Policy.SecondsToLive          := 0;
Result := HttpAddFragmentToCache( FQueueHandle, PWideChar( W ), Chunk, Policy );
```

Note: all overlapped parameters are made optionally nil / NULL in my code that explains why you might miss that parameter.

This will yield a result of 50 (The request is not supported). I tried to add fragments from memory and from file handle, All different policies. Checked if the values passed are correct in dis-assembly, Checked if the string passed to `HttpAddFragmentToCache` is indeed a valid subURL from the one passed to `HttpAddUrl` (if not you get an OS error 2 so that's also not it).

My question is: what could this be? I try to use this API call in the most straightforward manner I can see (it is where the API is designed for) but apparently I am doing something wrong..

**Update:**

It looks like that fragmens added with the function `HttpAddFragmentToCache` have a maximum size:

When the code above is replaced by:

```
Chunk.FromMemory.BufferLength := Min( 256*1024, Length( Content ) );
```

No errors occur; when replaced by

```
Chunk.FromMemory.BufferLength := Min( 256*1024 + 1, Length( Content ) );
```

It fails. Apparently there is a size limit and... I found it:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129

> UriMaxUriBytes     262144 (bytes) 
>   4096(4k) – 16777216(16MB) bytes    Any
>   response that is greater than this
>   value is not cached in the kernel
>   response cache.

This leaves two options: 1. keep multiple fragments for larger files. or 2. increase this limit in the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem: There is a limit in the size the fragment cache can cache per fragment; defaults to 256KB. See the update of the question for details.

Comment: I didn't know that! Nice catch! That's where chunking is coming around to circumvent this limitation. Using chunks of up to 256 KB, you can cache a file of any size. But I'm not sure there will be a speed benefit of caching such huge file size. Asynchronous reading from a file on disk would be better, because it will stay in memory if there is enough RAM. `HttpAddFragmentToCache` is meant for small static files (typically some .js .css or .jpg .png which are used everywhere in the website hosted by http.sys).

Comment: @Bouchez: Exactly. I only cought it because I wanted all static files, including extjs-all.js which is 1MB+, be added to fragments. It is exactly what you describe: static files (typically some .js .css or .jpg .png which are used everywhere in the website hosted by http.sys) except for the small part ;-).

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult without all source code of your implementation.

When do you call `HttpAddFragmentToCache` ? It should be before any call to `HttpReceiveHttpRequest`() in the client TThread instances.

For instance, your `HttpReceiveHttpRequest`() call sounds a bit strange to me. You should use

```
HttpReceiveRequestEntityBody( FQueueHandle, FRequest^.RequestID, ... )
```

Take a look at the `THttpApiServer` class in our [`SynCrtSock`](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCrtSock.pas) unit, to working example of the http.sys server. It does not support cache yet, but at least the main initialization and thread pool work as expected.

Comment: Yes I do call it before starting to process any request. I did look at your code and the processing loops looks quite similar (except that I use a more classic try with small buffer, get size and retry. That works quite well btw, no problems there, I just keep a local HTTP request ID next to the HTTP_REQUEST structure. My problem lies within the HttpAddFragmentToCache call and maybe I am missing something but I do not see any call to that function by your library. They are quite similar btw.

Comment: Or a link to it to a PasteBin site, for instance?